# Multi Component two way binding data transfer

Tags: angular

I am trying to carry data between 3 components (input) but it comes as 'undefined'

```
1: app.component
2: person.component
3: user.component
```

I want a selected data in user.component to come to app.component

```
user.component -> Select "Mark"
person.component -> user input "Mark"
app.component -> Click Button Log "Mark"
```

but it unknown.
I'm throwing a case study.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-94rfex

Comment: You will need to implements [@Ouput()](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event). But you have 2 nested levels, maybe you can find a better solution.

Comment: With "output" I feel like I am on the long way. I'm looking for a more optimized answer

Comment: What is the goal you're trying to achieve with this 3 component binding ?

Comment: Another solution is to pass by a service, which will store the data from `user.ts`, and retrieve it in `app.components.ts`

Comment: You can create one service, and declare that name variable there, and use service.name in 3 components without Output()

Comment: read docs: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 2):

There are many way to pass data between components. as @Emilien suggests, using '@output' is one of the options.

You could also use things such as

- services
- Observables.

Angular has good documentation around these various types -> [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)